Summation Sign Font
I noticed that the lecturer used a different sum sign in his notes but the general font seems to be the standard font to me.
How can I use such a summation sign?


https://ibb.co/nwQvVXr
This link should work.

as you have the pdf you can see exactly which fonts are used, you don't need to make us guess from an image.

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45919/how-do-i-find-out-what-fonts-are-used-in-a-document-picture

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Welcome to TeX.SX!

Updating 1: 2024/05/03
The \sum symbol is taken from pakage txfonts: see short MWE and of the figure.
%% Compile and read me!
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\[\sum^{n}_{i=1}{xcv}\]
\end{document}



With the engine XeLaTeX: For my humble opinion very close \sum symbol is given from STIX Two Math or Libertinus Math. I have tried also Cambria Math but it is big.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont[range={\sum}, Scale=MatchUppercase]{STIX Two Math}
\let\mathbb\relax % remove the definition by unicode-math
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbb}{U}{msb}{m}{n}
\begin{document}
The range of matrix $A\in\mathbb{K}^{I\times J}$ is
\[
\operatorname{range}(A)=\{Ax\colon x\in\mathbb{K}^{J}\}=\operatorname{span}\{A_{(j)},i\in J\}.
\]

Hence, the range of a matrix is a vector space spanned by its columns. The Euclidean scalar product in $\mathbb{K}^I$ is given by.
\[\langle x,y\rangle=y^Hx=\sum_{i\in I}x_i\bar{y}_i,\]
 
where for $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}$ the conjugate sign can be ignored. It is often useful and very

\end{document}


Using Libertinus Math (good):

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont[range={\sum}, Scale=MatchUppercase]{Libertinus Math}
\let\mathbb\relax % remove the definition by unicode-math
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbb}{U}{msb}{m}{n}
\begin{document}
The range of matrix $A\in\mathbb{K}^{I\times J}$ is
\[
\operatorname{range}(A)=\{Ax\colon x\in\mathbb{K}^{J}\}=\operatorname{span}\{A_{(j)},i\in J\}.
\]
Hence, the range of a matrix is a vector space spanned by its columns. The Euclidean scalar product in $\mathbb{K}^I$ is given by.
\[\langle x,y\rangle=y^Hx=\sum_{i\in I}x_i\bar{y}_i,\]
 where for $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}$ the conjugate sign can be ignored. It is often useful and very
\end{document}

With Cambria Math:

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont[range={\sum}, Scale=MatchUppercase]{Cambria Math}
\let\mathbb\relax % remove the definition by unicode-math
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbb}{U}{msb}{m}{n}
\begin{document}
The range of matrix $A\in\mathbb{K}^{I\times J}$ is
\[
\operatorname{range}(A)=\{Ax\colon x\in\mathbb{K}^{J}\}=\operatorname{span}\{A_{(j)},i\in J\}.
\]

Hence, the range of a matrix is a vector space spanned by its columns. The Euclidean scalar product in $\mathbb{K}^I$ is given by.
\[\langle x,y\rangle=y^Hx=\sum_{i\in I}x_i\bar{y}_i,\]
 
where for $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}$ the conjugate sign can be ignored. It is often useful and very

\end{document}

You can see also this TeX Gyre Pagella Math (good):

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont[range={\sum}, Scale=MatchUppercase]{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
\let\mathbb\relax % remove the definition by unicode-math
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbb}{U}{msb}{m}{n}
\begin{document}
The range of matrix $A\in\mathbb{K}^{I\times J}$ is
\[
\operatorname{range}(A)=\{Ax\colon x\in\mathbb{K}^{J}\}=\operatorname{span}\{A_{(j)},i\in J\}.
\]
Hence, the range of a matrix is a vector space spanned by its colunns. The Euclidean scalar product in $\mathbb{K}^I$ is given by.
\[\langle x,y\rangle=y^Hx=\sum_{i\in I}x_i\bar{y}_i,\]
where for $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}$ the conjugate sign can be ignored. It is often useful and very
\end{document}

with TeX Gyre Termes Math (good):

